# Check on the result of an update is failing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Every time I click on change password it will change the password but it prompts the invalid combination

Here is my code

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE LoginReport SET PassLogin = @NewPassLogin WHERE UserLogin = @UserLogin AND PassLogin = @PassLogin ", conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLogin", txtUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassLogin", txtOldPass.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPassLogin", txtNewPass.Text);

    SqlDataReader Dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (Dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Updated Account");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Combination");
    }
}
```

Why is the check failing?

Comment: You're running an `UPDATE`. By itself (without an `OUTPUT` clause), it generates no rows. Perhaps you meant to use `ExecuteNonQuery` and check the value it returns, which is the number of rows affected? Also, please don't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "Sucessfully Updated Account" : "Invalid Combination");`

Answer (score 6):

An `update` does not return any rows, a `select` does. Hence, `HasRows` is false.

You have to check another way if the update was succesful: by checking the result of `ExecuteNonQuery()`. It will return the rows affected. If that is more than 0, it was successful.

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Updated Account");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Combination");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `cmd.ExecuteReader();` you have to use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` which returns the number of affected rows.

```
int RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (RowsAffected == 1)
{     
     MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Updated Account");
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid Combination");
}
```

An Update Command does not return any rows so it's correct that `Dr.HasRows == true` returns `false`.

Answer (score 4):

You should have to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx).

> ExecuteNonQuery: Use this operation to execute any arbitrary SQL statements in SQL Server if you do not want any result set to be returned.

Comment: That doesn't answer why the code wasn't working, although it is the right solution.